# thriftmethod enum when upgrade version,the enum values got wrong

Tags: java, enums, thrift

i have question here.
my server and client use a enum like this.

```
@ThriftEnum
public enum UgcTypeEnum {

    UNKNOWN(0, "未知", null),

    // 猫眼问答
    QA_QUESTION(1, "ssss", null),

    QA_ANSWER(2, "sssss", UgcTypeEnum.QA_QUESTION)
}
```

when i upgraded the enum version like ,the server use it.

```
@ThriftEnum    
public enum UgcTypeEnum {

    UNKNOWN(0, "未知", null),

    QA_QUESTION(1, "ssss", null),

    QA_ANSWER_REPLY(3, "ssss", UgcTypeEnum.QA_ANSWER),

    QA_ANSWER(2, "sssss", UgcTypeEnum.QA_QUESTION)
}
```

when the client use older verion ,the server use new version ,the enum order is wrong.

why is this???

Comment: Because the enum order in the source code is different, so the internal `ordinal` assigned to the enum value is different. Change the order of QA_ANSWER and QA_ANSWER_REPLY on the server.

Comment: @Pete OP can't "move away" from the ordinal because OP is not using the ordinal themselves. That's done under the hood by thrift - an example of one of these sophisticated uses.